# How to identify an element through text?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to do some basic stuff with Selenium and I'm trying to find an element by the "Text" since all my elements are either dynamically generated or they have a common attribute name and value.

i would like to get to "SelTest" at the following div, here is one block:

```
 <div ng-mouseenter="hover=true" ng-mouseleave="hover=false" class="object workspace" ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces | filter:{'workspace_title':workspaceFilter, 'is_archived':false} | orderBy: 'workspace_title'" ui-sref="main.workspace({workspaceId: workspace.id})" href="#!/workspace/a43d95fa24acbfc4757ba86a4d8dec22">
            <i class="mdi mdi-folder"></i>
            <div class="title">SelTest</div>
            <div class="desc"></div>
            <div class="tools ng-hide" ng-show="hover" style="">
                <button type="button" ng-click="workspace.toggleArchive();$event.stopPropagation();" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                    <span>Archive</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

while the rest of the code have the same exact attribute name and value.

and here is the bigger picture:

[image]

Is there anyway to get to **SelTest**?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the text **SetTest** or you are trying to identify the element with text as **SetTest**?

Comment: cant you get the element by using content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('SetTest');

Comment: @DebanjanB, im trying to get the element with text as SetTest

Comment: @VSB, no because .find_element_by_class_name is not an acceptable argument

Comment: @Ali There is no element with text as **SetTest** but there is one element with text as **SelTest**. I have updated your question accordingly. Feel free to revert back the edit if it is wrong.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore HTML got broken because of a bad edit, I am reverting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element with text as **SelTest** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement ele = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.object.workspace[ng-repeat^='workspace in workspaces'][href*='workspace'] div.title")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement ele = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='object workspace' and starts-with(@ng-repeat, 'workspace in workspaces')][contains(@href, 'workspace')]//div[@class='title' and text()='SelTest']")));
  ```

Comment: I had no idea about ExpectedConditions which is great and that xpath THOUGH! thank you very much. your answer made me realize I have to go through my codes again. thank you